# Local JavaScript obfuscator

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I have been looking all day for a decent JavaScript obfuscator. Most of the tools I have found are quirky if useful at all.

I'm not concerned with reverse engineering. I need obfuscation to hide as much domain-specific information as possible from the user.

Comment: http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home

Comment: What tools have you found? In what form does that domain specific information appear in your script?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/194397/how-can-i-obfuscate-javascript

Comment: Šime Vidas: I tried some of the following 
For Obfuscation: Stunnix and a couple of other products

For Minification:
dojo shrinksafe
yui compressor
google closurecompiler

The domain specific information relates to names than might cue an intruder in on database names, table names etc.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Free JavaScript Obfuscator](http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx)? Its job is to make your code as unreable as possible.

There's also [Google Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) if you perfer, but it doesn't obfuscate as much as the former.

Comment: This has already been suggested in a comment above...

Comment: I would like to compile on my own system

Answer (score 1):

I *always* use [closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), which has an api as well as a gui. The gui is a bit more difficult, but once you have it set up, it compiles your code into better code and obfuscates at the same time!

Comment: But as far as i know it does not obfuscate, only compress

Comment: [Here's](http://www.computercabal.com/2011/04/google-closure-compiler-using.html) some articles that may [help](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#dangers). Closure compiler compiles your code to make it unrealistic for a person to reverse engineer it.